# SSH recursively change all subfolders names to a specific name

Tags: ssh, find, exec, superuser

i have hundreads of folders with a subfolder named "thumbs" under each folder. i need to change the "thumbs" subfolder name with "thumb", under each subfolder.

i tried

```
find . -type d -exec rename 's/^thumbs$/thumb/' {} ";"
```

and i run this in shell when i am inside the folder that contains all subfolders, and each one of these subfolders contains the "thumbs" folder that need to be renamed with "thumb".

well I ran that command and shell stayed a lot of time thinking, then i gave a CTRL+C to stop, but I checked and no folder was renamed under current directory, I dont know if i renamed folders outside the directory i was in, can someone tell me where i am wrong with the code?

Comment: Please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: i dont know how to move, i searched but i cant find the info.

Comment: Delete here, re-post there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Goal 1:**  To change a subfolder "thumbs" to "thumb" if only one level deep.

**Example Input:**

```
./foo1/thumbs
./foo2/thumbs
./foo2/thumbs
```

**Solution:**

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d | sed 'p;s/thumbs/thumb/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

**Output:**

```
./foo1/thumb
./foo2/thumb
./foo2/thumb
```

**Explanation:**

Use `find` to give you all "thumbs" folders only **one** level deep.  Pipe the output to `sed`.  The `p` option prints the input line and the rest of the `sed` command changes "thumbs" to "thumb".  Finally, pipe to `xargs`.  The `-n2` option tells `xargs` to use **two** arguments from the pipe and pass them to the `mv` command.

**Issue:**

This will not catch deeper subfolders.  You can't simple not use depth here because `find` prints the output from the top and since we are replacing things with `sed` before we `mv`, `mv` will result in a error for deeper subfolders.  For example, ./foo/thumbs/thumbs/ will not work because `mv` will take care of ./foo/thumbs first and make it ./foo/thumb, but then the next output line will result in an error because ./foo/thumbs/thumbs/ no longer exist.

**Goal 2:**  To change **all** subfolders "thumbs" to "thumb" regardless of how deep.

**Example Input:**

```
./foo1/thumbs
./foo2/thumbs
./foo2/thumbs/thumbs
./foo2/thumbs
```

**Solution:**

```
find . -type d | awk -F'/' '{print NF, $0}' | sort -k 1 -n -r | awk '{print $2}' | sed 'p;s/\(.*\)thumbs/\1thumb/' | xargs -n2 mv
```

**Output:**

```
./foo1/thumb
./foo2/thumb
./foo2/thumb/thumb
./foo2/thumb
```

**Explanation:**

Use `find` to give you all "thumbs" subfolders.  Pipe the output to `awk` to print the number of '/'s in each path plus the original output.  `sort` the output numerically, in reverse (to put the deepest paths on top) by the number of '/'s. Pipe the sorted list to `awk` to remove the counts from each line.  Pipe the output to `sed`.  The `p` option prints the input line and the rest of the `sed` command finds the **last** occurrence of "thumbs" and changes only it to "thumb".  Since we are working with sorted list in the order of deepest to shallowest level, this will provide `mv` with the right commands.  Finally, pipe to `xargs`.  The `-n2` option tells `xargs` to use **two** arguments from the pipe and pass them to the `mv` command.